# How to check if a repository is cloned via HTTP or ssh?

Tags: git, http, ssh, configuration

I need a quick way to understand whether the repo, I am in, is cloned via HTTP or ssh? Looking for a command from Git or any other configuration checkpoint to provide this info for me.

Comment: Are you asking for something like `git remote`, possibly with `-v`?

Comment: @mkrieger1 How does that show the information I need, git remote shows "origin" and with -v it prints out the full source/url of the repo.

Comment: @NaserNikzad the url should indicate the protocol. You might also need to check for git configs such as `url.xxx.insteadOf`

Comment: Thanks @mkrieger1 the full command showed the url and you were right that url shows the protocol `git remote show origin`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This command will show you [the URLs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#_git_urls) that the repo will fetch from and push to by *default*<sup>1</sup>:

```sh
git remote show origin
```

From the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#_git_urls):

> In general, URLs contain information about the transport protocol, the address of the remote server, and the path to the repository. Depending on the transport protocol, some of this information may be absent.
>
> Git supports ssh, git, http, and https protocols (in addition, ftp, and ftps can be used for fetching, but this is inefficient and deprecated; do not use it).

While it's not a guarantee that it's where the repository was cloned from in the first place (since you can easily change the URL associated with a remote by using the [`--set-url`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote#Documentation/git-remote.txt-emset-urlem) option of [`git remote`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote)), it's a pretty safe bet in most cases.

---

1. Where by "default", I mean if you just do `git fetch` or `git push` without specifying the name of a remote.

Comment: So, here are the outputs from both ssh and https versions

Fetch URL: git@pomtechgit.com:HeratGlobal/aim-test.git [Cloned via SSH]

Fetch URL: https://pomtechgit.com/HeratGlobal/aim-test.git [Cloned via HTTPS]

am I right?

Comment: Yes, looks about right.